# Jquery.Нужно добавить Class, после того как n-количество блоков скроются.Помогите

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть 6 блоков с checkbox. При Нажатии на которые, они скрываются:

```
$( 'input[type=checkbox]' ).click(function(){
        $('.catalog:has(input:checked)')
            .animate({ opacity: "0.5"},1000)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000);

});
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после скрытия данных блоков (`display:none`), поверх добавлялся `DIV` c текстом.

Пытался реализовать вот так:

```
var countCatalog=$('.catalog').length;
var catalogNone=$('.catalog:hidden').length;

$(function () {
    if ($(countCatalog)==(catalogNone)){
        $('.work').addClass('.new__block');
    }
});
```

но не работает(

Также пытался длину `input:checked` с длиной просто `input` и потом уже добавить новый Class. 
Прошу помочь, неделю уже мучаюсь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

**UPD.** Внимательнее прочитал, что нужно сделать и переделал код. Теперь вроде работает как надо.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var checkedLength = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  $(this)
    .animate({
      opacity: "0.5"
    }, 1000)
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeOut(1000, function() {
      if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').length == checkedLength) {
        $('.checkbox-parent').append('<div class="add-box">Нажимать больше нечего</div>');
      };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-parent">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)))Попробую применить код у себя))Если что, знаю куда обратится))

Answer (score 0):

В код не вчитывался, но уже вижу проблему в `$(countCatalog)==(catalogNone)`
`$(countCatalog)` - это вызов jQuery с передачей числа. Результатом будет массив с одним элементом - этим числом. Т.е.:

```
$(1) -> [1]
```

И получается, что Вы сравниваете массив с числом, поэтому результат всегда `false`.

Еще Вы неправильно добавляете класс, нужно писать без точки `.`:

```
$('.work').addClass('new__block');
```

Comment: Только учусь) Невнимательность( Так как мне сделать в итоге? вот так?   
     if ($(countCatalog)==$(catalogNone)){
            $('.work').addClass('new__block');
        }
    });

Comment: И будет у вас [1] == [1] -> false.
Зачем jQuery вызывать? Просто сравните два числа: countCatalog==catalogNone. Обычный Js

Comment: Не знаю,все равно не работает(   var countCatalog=$('.catalog').length;
    var catalogNone=$('.catalog:hidden').length;
      $(function () {
        if (countCatalog==catalogNone){
            $('.work').addClass('new__block')
        }
    });